# Stopping PHP Form from re-sending and strange issue

Tags: php, html, forms

okay, I'll keep it short.

I have this code:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['title'] != 'Title') && ($_POST['date'] != 'Date')
{
$fileName = 'blog.txt';
$fp = fopen('blog.txt', 'a');
$savestring = PHP_EOL . "<h2><center><span>" . $_POST['title'] . "</span></center></h2>" . PHP_EOL . "<div class=fright><p><em>|<br><strong>| Posted:</strong><br>| " . $_POST['date'] . "<br>|</p></em></div></p></em>" . PHP_EOL . "<p><em>" . $_POST['paragraph'] . "</em></p>" . PHP_EOL . "<hr>";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);              
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

And this HTML Form:

```
<form action="acp.html" method="post">
<input value="Title" name="title" class="txt" id="title">
<input value="Date" name="date" class="txt" id="date">
<input value="Content" name="paragraph" class="txt" id="paragraph">
<button class="btn">Add Post!</button>
</form>
```

I also have a PHP script that opens the blog.txt file content. Now, I have a set of problems. This is my first PHP script made ever, I'm aware it's possible with MySQL too but I want to start with easy stuffs. The current script works pretty well, but if I refresh the page that contains the form it will re-post it all. I've tried to make a checkbox and make it only post when the checkbox is ticked, but either I did something wrong either this is not possible as I was simply not able to get it to work.

Finally, for some unknown reasons, when I enter the page that contains the form for the first time it will just do the $savestring part without getting any data at all from the 3 custom fields.

So my final needs are:
Is there a way to add a checkbox that will not save, and make the script only work when the checkbox is ticked ?

Could you also tell me why when I enter the script for the first time the script is executed without getting any data from the 's ?

P.S: I've included the PHP script in the , could that be a reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ($_POST['title'] != 'Title') && ($_POST['date'] != 'Date')` [will always be true when you first load the page](http://codepad.org/8UElPHrl). Since `$_POST['title']` and `$_POST['date']` are not set they won't equal anything must less your expected values.

You should add an additional check to make sure the page is being requested using POST:

```
if (
    'POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && 
    ($_POST['title'] != 'Title') 
     && ($_POST['date'] != 'Date')
)
```

Comment: Ok, now when I enter the page the blank form is no longer added but the resending still occurs when i refresh th page.

Comment: That's a different issue. See [this article I wrote](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-6-Preventing-Duplicate-Submissions/ba-p/11168) to see how to prevent that from happening.

Comment: You method is good but it's quite comp,exx considering my script is for an admin panel which only i'll see. Isn't it possible to clear session data without so much code?

Comment: Since it's not session data that won't work. The way I mentioned is your only choice and it really isn't very difficult to implement. Just do a redirect back to the same page after you're done processing the form. That's all you need to do.